# MongoDB query for last embedded document, with specific attribute, in document array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I have a MongoDB database (hosted as a Cosmos DB), where my documents have an array of embedded documents, something like this:

```
{
    "computer": "comp01",
    "reports": [
        {
            "os": "windows 10",
            "manufacturer": "dell"
        },
        {
            "os": "windows 11",
            "hdd": "500GB"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "computer": "comp02",
    "reports": [
        {
            "os": "windows 8",
            "manufacturer": "hp",
            "hdd": "240GB"
        },
        {
            "os": "Manjaro"
        },
        {
            "hdd": "300GB"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want do a query where only certain documents in the array are included in the results. The returned embedded documents, should be where a specific attribute is present.
E.g. for os, it would be the latest document that contains the attribute:

```
[{
    "computer": "comp01",
    "reports": [
        {
            "os": "windows 11",
            "hdd": "500GB"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "computer": "comp02",
    "reports": [
        {
            "os": "Manjaro"
        }
    ]
}]
```

Alternatively the value os in the embedded documents, with no other attributes or empty documents:

```
[{
    "computer": "comp01",
    "reports": [
        { "os": "windows 10" },
        { "os": "windows 11" }
    ]
},
{
    "computer": "comp02",
    "reports": [
        { "os": "windows 8" },
        { "os": "Manjaro" }
    ]
}]
```

or this, with only the last value of the attribute:

```
[{
    "computer": "comp01",
    "reports": [
        {
            "os": "windows 11"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "computer": "comp02",
    "reports": [
        {
            "os": "Manjaro"
        }
    ]
}]
```

I've tried a few things that does parts of this, but it always seems to be a bit off. My most notable attempts (closest to the desired results) are:

1. Projection

   `db.collection.find({},{"reports.os":1 })`

This returns empty documents for the array documents, which I haven't been able to find a way to disable.
I.e.

```
[{
    "computer": "comp01",
    "reports": [
        { "os": "windows 10" },
        { "os": "windows 11" }
    ]
},
{
    "computer": "comp02",
    "reports": [
        { "os": "windows 8" },
        { "os": "Manjaro" },
        { }
    ]
}}
```

2. ElemMatch

   `db.collection.find( {}, { reports: { $elemMatch: {"os":{$exists: true}} } } )`

Which returns the entire document of the first matched embedded document. This could be acceptable if it was possible to return the last match instead. It doesn't seem like this is a possibility though(?).

3. slices

   `db.collection.find({}, {"computer":1, reports: {$slice:-1}} )`

With something like this I've been able to obtain the last document in the array, which again could be acceptable to my use case, if I was ensured the sought attribute was in it. The problem here would in the example data case be that I wouldn't be able to extract the os from the computer comp02.

It would be very appreciated if anyone could help shed some light on how to get the data on one or more of the three forms explained in the beginning, or knew, with certainty, if what I am trying to do is impossible in MongoDB queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aggregation query to get the desired result:

- First filter the array to remove elements where key is not `os`.
- And then `$project` to output desired values using `$slice` to get the las position in the array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "reports": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$reports",
          "as": "r",
          "cond": {"$ne": [undefined,"$$r.os"]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "computer": 1,
      "reports": {
        "$slice": ["$reports",-1]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d3xYM0rL8iJ)